# persist cordova plugin object on navigation between pages

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Is it possible to persist a plugin object on cordova when I navigate through pages? I tried multview phonegap plugin but it does not work, it always crashes and I've found no solution, even on most simplest examples.

Edit1: Program my own plugin is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just link cordova.js on any .html where you want to use plugins.